# What is "noticierismo"?

Tags: definiciones

> La prensa, tanto la de Cádiz como la de Madrid, se ocupó del asunto sin poner en duda la existencia de la Mano Negra y creando una atmósfera de miedo a base de artículos sensacionalistas sobre la «abominable asociación», «aborto de la demencia y el crimen», como uno publicado en El Cronista de Jerez en el que se decía que los miembros de la Mano Negra estaban obligados a matar a la persona que se les designaba y que si no lo hacían eran asesinados a su vez.​ El «**noticierismo**» de la prensa también fue denunciado por La Revista Social.
>
> > [source](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Mano_Negra#Los_%C2%ABcr%C3%ADmenes_de_La_Mano_Negra%C2%BB), citing Avilés Farré, Juan (2013). *La daga y la dinamita. Los anarquistas y el nacimiento del terrorismo.* Barcelona: Tusquets Editores. p. 150. ISBN 978-84-8383-753-5.

Can't find a definition online. Something based off of "news", perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From "[noticiero](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QeTye5x)" and "[-ismo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MBKXJUu)".
It means "producing news as if it was a competition", i.e. as opposed to producing actual, true-to-facts news.